# How to access history in Seamonkey?

Tags: firefox, history, seamonkey

Seamonkey is so close to Firefox, but I cannot access history like in Firefox. Is this feature accessible in Seamonkey?

[image]

Comment: when downvote, please leave a comment to let me see what is wrong with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit discrete, but it is there:

CTRL-H

or

Go - History

[image]